# Finding Closed Loop Subset with the least number of elements

Tags: algorithm, search

Here is the problem I am problem I am trying to solve. I have a set of "Like" elements that define a person liking another person. For example, one element would have the information "John likes Jane". Another might have "Jane likes Joseph" and so on. I would like to know what would be the best algorithm to determine

1. Least number of elements that together would forma closed loop. In the above example, if we have another element "Joseph likes John" then the 3 elements together would form a closed loop
2. The list of elements could be huge

I was looking at the Travelling Salesman algorithm. But it doesnt provide me the Least number of nodes to form a closed loop

Appreciate your help

Comment: Dykstra's anyone? Depends on how you store the relations, a MVCE would be nice. Graph seems like the option here as the matrix would be sparse. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask The algorithm will differ greatly depending on your data structure

Comment: Also see this great answer to a [similarly vague question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857842/find-shortest-path/) :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/26858645/3255525

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find cycle of shortest length in a directed graph with positive weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911626/find-cycle-of-shortest-length-in-a-directed-graph-with-positive-weights)

Comment: As I commented above, this is really a graph problem. The people are the nodes and the edges are people liking other people. Each edge in your problem has weight 1, and you want to find the smallest cycle (what most mathematicians call your "loop") in a given graph (set of "who likes who" data).

Comment: Dijkstra’s algorithm requires all the elements to be part of the final closed loop. in my case, out of say 100 elements, the above 3 elements simply form a closed loop. So I dont care about the other 97

Answer (score 0):

Start with the first person.

Follow the chain of people they like, storing each each person inside an array. Once you reach a duplicate person it means you have reached a loop, To find the length of this loop you find the 2 occurences of the person say in `personarr[X]` and `personarr[Y]` and do Y - X.  Store the length of this loop along with any member inside it.

Now, making sure to keep your `personarr[]` you will move onto the second person. If they are not in the array then add them to it and repeat first step, otherwise move onto third person. Each time you find a new loop update your 'best loop' information.

Comment: This method was my first instinct, but I think it assumes that each person has a unique like... for example you may have two elements "Bob likes Jim" and "Bob likes Sue"... so which one gets to join your chain?

Comment: oh I assumed that each person likes only one person

Answer (score 0):

First you need to realize that in the worst case here you **have** to go over the entire list of elements at least once.

An example which show this is a graph with [image: 3n+2] vertices in which each triplet of the first [image: 3n] vertices forms a triangle and the last [image: 2] vertices "like" each other. You have to find those two in order to see that the least number of elements you're looking for is [image: 2], and in the worst case you find them last, just like when you're looking for your keys.

After you realize this your question basically becomes the question of finding the smallest cycle in an unweighted directed graph. The best solution I can think of right now is running BFS from each node to find the shortest cycle to itself and then taking the minimum of all results. The run time complexity for this is [image: O(V^2)].

I performed a quick search and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703557/algorithm-for-finding-shortest-cycles-in-directed-graph) in which what I just said is suggested with someone claiming it's the best way to do it. There's also an answer suggesting another way by using DFS, which takes [image: O(V+E)], but since [image: E=O(V^2)] it doesn't asymptotically improve anything in the worst case.